# no root partition was found : FreeBSD

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, mount, freebsd

I want to install freeBSD in my laptop.

I already had a Ubuntu at my system.

I make the partition of 40GB using GParted, to install freeBSD in to that.

But when I install freeBSD on the partition having 40GB , the error comes like "No root partition was found , the root FreeBSD partition must have a mountpoint of '/'".

can you suggest me how to solve this issue ?

Comment: Add a root partition

Comment: @EricF can I mount two partition at same mountpoint '/'

Comment: I don't believe so. I could be wrong but I do believe the mount points have to be different.

Comment: @EricF so now what is the sollution ?

Comment: Did you actually create a root partition (and possibly also other partitions) or did you only create a slice ?

Comment: @Hennes : I think it is just a slice. , because I used a software called GParted , I shrink one of the partition , and then create a new partition with un-allocated space.

Comment: Could you add the output of the partition table to your post? (e.g. from Ubuntu do a `fdisk -l /dev/sda` or the [gpart](http://scratching.psybermonkey.net/2010/06/freebsd-how-to-format-partition.html) equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Using FreeBSD you need to create a slice; next create and format volumes in that slice.

For comparion look at this Linux and windows setup with:

- A MBR used for the partition table
- Two primary partions
- One extended partition.
- For volumes, one in partition 1, one in partition 2, two volume in the extended partition.

These volumes can be mounted, e.g with the help of drive letters, or under a folder of an NTFS filesystem.

```
----------------------------Disk------------------------

MBR | Partition 1 | partition 2 | partition 4           |

    | Volume 1    | volume 2    | volume 3 | volume 4   |
```

---

Now consider FreeBSD, old style:

```
----------------------------Disk------------------------

MBR | slice                                             |

    | Volume 1    | volume 2    | volume 3 | volume 4   |
```

The slice is almost the same as an [extended] partition.
You need to create volumes in it and mount them.

---

To make it a tad more complex, here is the FreeBSD setup which is currently commom and which uses the traditional PC setup.

```
----------------------------Disk-------------------------

MBR | Partition 1 | partition 2         | partition 4   |

    | Volume 1    | Slice 1             | vol 4 | vol 5 |
                    vol2, vol 3, swap,
```

As I read you post I wonder if you created free space by moving partitions,
then created a slice for FreeBSD, but failed to create volume in that.

One of those volumes would have been mounted at /.

<sup>(Posted as a post since I see no way I could put all of this in a comment)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

> But when I install freeBSD on the partition having 40GB , the error
>   comes like "No root partition was found, the root FreeBSD partition
>   must have a mountpoint of '/'".

The way I read the above, you've successfully installed FreeBSD, but, when you tried to reboot into it, you got the error.

Please, update your answer to confirm my assumption -- or provide more details -- and I'll update the answer.